# If an object is moving with a velocity and a force acts upon it for a short period of time would it stop or move with a velocity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration

Suppose I push an object and a force acts in the opposite direction of motion for a short period of time which reduces the velocity suppose the object was moving with a velocity of 50m/s and was slowed down to 40m/s in a time period of 1second so after say 10seconds would the object have stopped or would move with a velocity?

Comment: What did you try, so far?

Comment: Archimedes and Galilei would give different answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will restate Newton's first law:

> An object in motion stays in motion unless acted upon by an unbalanced force, and an object at rest stays at rest unless acted upon by an unbalanced force

So, if no forces act on the block/all the forces are balanced (i.e. net force is zero), then after 10 seconds the block will move with the same velocity of $40\; \rm m/s$; after 10 hours it will still move with the same velocity.

Unless there is a net external force, the velocity does not change.

Comment: Please don't answer HW%E exercise Qs...